# Mpl toolkits plot_surface not showing any output

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, signal-processing

I am trying to plot z transforms of some signals using the `mpl_toolkits` in python, but the output is totally blank. What am I doing wrong? The input `numpy` arrays have non-zero values. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

# initialize r and theta 
r = 10
theta = r*np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,100)
theta = np.meshgrid(theta,theta)[0]
# calculate z
z = r*(np.cos(theta) + 1j*np.sin(theta))
# calculate z transform for first signal
xs1 = np.abs(z/(z-2))
# calculate z transform for second signal
xs2 = np.abs((np.power(z,3)+2*np.power(z,2)+3*z+3)/np.power(z,3))
# plot the transforms
fig1 = plt.figure(0)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
fig2 = plt.figure(1)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax1.plot_surface(z.real,z.imag,xs1,cmap = cm.coolwarm)
ax2.plot_surface(z.real,z.imag,xs2,cmap = cm.coolwarm)
plt.show()
```

Here is one of the output:
[image]

Comment: `z` is periodic. It's a bit hard to imagine how periodic coordinates are to be shown.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but why are no values being shown? how else should I plot this then?

Comment: Maybe as a scatter plot, `ax2.scatter(z.real, z.imag, xs2)`?